# How to get data from multiple SELECT statements and store it in the DataSet

Tags: c#, firebird

I am trying to execute multiple SELECT statements, such as,

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

string sql = @"SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
               SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE AGE > 40;";

using (FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(ConectionString))
{
    try
    {
        using (FbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        using (FbDataAdapter sda = new FbDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();
            sda.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
    catch (FbException e)
    {
        Error = e.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}

return ds;
```

The above code works great for one SELECT statement, but it throws an exception when there are multiple SELECT statements.

```
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 2, column 1
SELECT
```

I have tried the FbBatchExecution as well but I don't know how to get the returned data from it. It works well when using multiple INSERT or DELETE statements.

Comment: You can't execute multiple selects in a single command. BTW: What do you hope to achieve by selecting all customers, followed by selecting customers with `age > 40`.

Comment: it is just an example and not a real queries :) the real queries can be anything, e.g, fetching data from multiple tables

Comment: Well, nor Firebird, nor its ADO.net provider support this, you'll need to execute individually.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel for SQL Server it works when using similar code e.g. by using SqlConnection instead FbConnection an so on

Comment: Yes, but Firebird is not SQL Server; Firebird doesn't support multiple statements nor multiple result sets on a single execute, nor does the Firebird ADO.net provider attempt to simulate such a feature.

Comment: You can use Dapper. It's useful to read multiple object with single query.

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim That doesn't help you if you want to execute multiple queries at once.

Answer (score 2):

You have to build ONE query out of those two using SQL `UNION` operator

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)#UNION_operator
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-select.html#fblangref25-dml-select-union

Note how these your queries fetch the same rows: the first query has all the rows of the second plus some more

```
 SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
 SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE AGE > 40;
```

Basically you have two ways to link them together

```
 SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
     UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE AGE > 40
```

and

```
 SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
     UNION DISTINCT
 SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE AGE > 40
```

The first option would just link one query after another, without caring what the data they have brought. And unless you add `ORDER BY` clause it also would most probably keep the order of rows produced by sequential queries, just because it is easier to do so. However there is no warranty on that in neither SQL standard nor Firebird documentation, in other words that is purely "implementation detail" and there is some chance that in future rows would get reordered interleaving the queries even with `UNION ALL` w/o `ORDER BY` link (for example if the subqueries would be spawn into different processors for parallelization).

The second option would sort the outputs in temporary buffers and exclude duplicates, which would mean more working time for the server and more volume in memory and/or disk used for that temporary buffers and sorting, but would ensure you do not have duplicates in the rows (which means your specific queries would have then the same set of data as the first query alone).

Comment: actually, the queries I mentioned are not real, it was just an example, so how I will get data if I want to retrieve data from two different tables like

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS;

It is just an example and real queries can be anything and can also be more than two queries.

What I want is to store each query result to DataTable.

Comment: IMHO, it's doubtful to create a result that needs a lot of additional analysis on the client side. You could also convert all data to text or XML, pass it to the client as a single BLOB/CLOB field and let the client convert it back to structured data. But would that be wise?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas exactly as shown above - by combining several SELECT statements into one query using unions. The links in my answer provide more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to SQL Server, Firebird doesn't support execution of multiple statements in a single execute, nor can a single execute produce multiple result sets. If you want to execute multiple statements, you will need to execute them individually.

You also can't use `FbBatchExecution` because that is for executing inserts, updates, deletes, etc (statements that don't produce a result set).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know FbConnection provider, but if implement IDbConnection, so you can maybe use Dapper and then your problem solve this:
https://dapper-tutorial.net/querymultiple

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID; SELECT * FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;";

using (var connection = My.ConnectionFactory())
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {InvoiceID = 1}))
    {
        var invoice = multi.Read<Invoice>().First();
        var invoiceItems = multi.Read<InvoiceItem>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this just maps to a single execute - which I think it will - then this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(key))
        {
            try
            {
            sql.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
            SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE AGE > 40;";
            cmd.Connection = sql;
            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                   //First query data
                }
                if (dr.NextResult())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {   
                          //Second Query Data
                        }
                     }
                 }

              }
              }
              catch (FbException e)
              {
                   Error = e.Message;
              }
              finally
              {
                   sql .Close();
              }
          }
```